# Getting the value from id tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    var parts = $('#gitrepo').attr('value'); 
    alert(parts);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="gitrepo">http://github.com/username/repo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I need extract the value to the parts variable in the script, and split it by '/'. I was able to split it by '/' using .split('/') when i pass a string to parts, like `var parts="http://www.github.com",` but when i try to take it from the html using the id tag, the alert shows 'undefined' for the value of 'parts'. How can i extract the value between `<p></p>` that has the `id"gitrepo"?`

I tried `$('#gitrepo').val();` too, but did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.attr('value');` gets the value of the `value` attribute. That element has no `value` attribute. You're looking for its text:

```
$('#gitrepo').text()
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried $('#gitrepo').val(); too, but that did not work either. I read in the documentation that .val(); returns array. Is that why it was showing undefined?

Comment: @learningnothing: `.val()` returns a string. It's used for input elements, not paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of `.attr('value');`. There is no value attribute for `p` tag and value attribute is generally valid for an input elements and for html tags like `p` you can use .text()/.html() to extract its contents.

```
 $("p").click(function(){
    var parts = $('#gitrepo').text(); 
    alert(parts);
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your script. Note:

```
var parts = $('#gitrepo').html();
```

instead of

```
var parts = $('#gitrepo').attr('value'); 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    var parts = $('#gitrepo').html(); 
    alert(parts);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```